# Can a wifi repeater connect to a wifi with sign-in access?

Tags: wireless-networking

I'm currently staying in a hotel and will be staying there for more than a month. The hotel free wifi has a sign-in access, but the signal is weak. 
I was wondering if a travel wifi repeater will be able to connect to a wireless connection with sign-in access?

Thanks!

Comment: At most, the repeater simply operates as a layer-2 switch; some just operate at the physical layer. It doesn't care about the sign-in operation which takes place at layers 5 and above. More information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model